# Which files should I tell my VCS to ignore when using Sphinx for documentation?

Tags: python, git, version-control, python-sphinx

I want to start using [Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org) to document my project. I told Sphinx to use separate source and build directories during `sphinx-quickstart`. Now my directory layout is the following:

```
MyProject/
    myproject/
        __init__.py
        mymodule.py
    docs/
        source/
            .static/
            .templates/
            conf.py
            index.rst
        build/
        Makefile
```

Which files should be excluded from a VCS repository for a Sphinx project (i.e., since I use Git, what should I add to my `.gitignore` file)? For example, should I ignore the `docs/build/` directory so that changes in the HTML pages generated from Sphinx aren't tracked?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you take a look at the contents of `Makefile` you'll see something as follows:

```
BUILDDIR      = build

...

clean:
    -rm -rf $(BUILDDIR)/*
```

This means that `make clean` just removes the `build` directory so, with regard to version control, ignoring the contents of the `build` directory should be enough as you already suspected.

Comment: Note that if you use [sphinx-apidoc](http://sphinx-doc.org/man/sphinx-apidoc.html), almost all (except `index.rst`) `*.rst` files in `docs` will get generated and can be ignored, too. I would suggest an ignore rule like `/docs/myproject.*`.

Comment: But if you want to preserve the final files (html, pdf, etc.) for users so they don't have to rebuild the documentation, then build/ should be committed, but is every file in build/ needed to read the documentation, or can some be ignored?

Answer (score 10):

If you create a new project on GitHub, it will offer to create a Python-flavored `.gitignore` file for you.  This file includes [one reference](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/f651f0d3/Python.gitignore#L67-L68) to Sphinx-generated files:

```
# Sphinx documentation
docs/_build/
```

Note:  This assumes that you accept the defaults when you run `sphinx-quickstart`.  You may need to adjust it depending on how you answered these questions:

1. Root path:

   ```
   Enter the root path for documentation.
   > Root path for the documentation [.]:
   ```

   This determines the path where documentation is stored.  If you made it something other than `docs`, then you'll need to update `.gitignore` accordingly.
2. Build directory:

   ```
   You have two options for placing the build directory for Sphinx output.
   Either, you use a directory "_build" within the root path, or you separate
   "source" and "build" directories within the root path.
   > Separate source and build directories (y/n) [n]:
   ```

   If you answered `n` (default), then Sphinx will create the build directory at `<root>/_build` (your source files will be stored directly under `<root>/`).

   If you answered `y`, then Sphinx will create the build directory at `<root>/build` (your source files will be stored in `<root>/source`).

   Note the presence/absence of the leading underscore; make sure the corresponding pattern in your `.gitignore` matches.